# how to Transfer data from a table to another table with more columns?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have one table with 20 columns that I need to transfer to a new table with 25 columns.
I was wonder if there is any possibility to do so? I will much appreciate any source that will lead me to solution.
Thank you so much for your time and help.

I will make a short example below:

table.1 includes, let's say 4 columns in this order:
t1.First_name, t1.last_name, t1.Phone_number, t1.Address

and I want to transfer this data to Table.2 that includes these columns in this order:
t2.First_name, t2.Last_name, t2.Gender, t2.Phone_number, t2.Phone_type, t2.Address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table2 ( First_name, Last_name, Gender, Phone_number, Phone_type, Address)
SELECT  First_name, last_name, 'M', Phone_number, 'cell', Address
FROM    table1
```

For columns that don't exist in source table you need to provide default values or NULL, and update them later.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the the extra columns - do they support NULL values, etc..?

Typically you could do something like an INSERT INTO... SELECT (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2522/insert-into-sql-server-table-with-select-command/)

e.g.

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[table2] (First_name, Last_name, Gender, Phone_number, Phone_type, Address)
    SELECT First_name, last_name, NULL, Phone_number, NULL, Address
    FROM [dbo].[table1]
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help @FiddlyDigital and thanks for the source you shared

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into t2(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,PHONE_NUMBER,ADDRESS) 
(select * from t1);
```

Comment: Thanks for putting time and answer Abhi